# How to hide three dot option in ace editor

Tags: javascript, html

How can I hide this three dot option (attached image) in ace editor. This does not show when I open the html in Desktop web browser, but it is showing when I open it on android webview.
Referring this Library (ACE Editor): https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just found out. Didn't got the actual function to do this but it can be done by modifying ace.js file.

In ace.js file, line 3157 (may be different in your case).

```
contextMenu.style.display = "";
```

Make it none:

```
contextMenu.style.display = "none";
```

That's it.

So the actual question was how to hide contextmenu of ace editor.